# Length minimizing property of geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

I want to show that isometries map geodesics to geodesic using that an isometry of two riemannian manifolds also implies an isometry of metric spaces. 
I have found proofs using the length minimizing properties of geodesics but I don't really see how this works yet:

Let $(M,g), (N,h)$ be Riemannian manifolds and $F: M \rightarrow N$ an isometry.

The length minimizing property is local, correct? So for some point I have a normal neighborhood $U$ for some point $p \in M$, then for each point $q\in U$ there exists a unique geodesic $\gamma$  connecting $p$ and $q$. I also know that than it holds
$d(p,q)=L(\gamma)=\int\limits_a^b \sqrt{g(\gamma'(s),\gamma'(s))} \ ds$

Now if I have a geodesic from $p$ to $q$, then

$L(F(\gamma))=L(\gamma)=d(p,q)=d(F(p),F(q))$

can I then conclude, that $F(\gamma)$ is a geodesic, correct?

How can I deduce the statement for general geodesics (not only those in a normal neighborhood)?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an intervall $I$ a smooth curve $\gamma: I\to M$ is  a geodesic iff the following two conditions hold:

> 1. $|\gamma'|$ is constant
> 2. $\gamma$ is locally shortest, i.e. for all $t\in I$ there is a neighbourhood $J$ of $t$ such that for all $r,s\in J$ with $r\leq s$ $\gamma$ restricted to $[r,s]$ is the shortest smooth curve between $\gamma(r)$ and $\gamma(s)$

Now if $\gamma: I\to M$ is a geodesic and $F:M\to N$ an isometry then 
$$|(F\circ\gamma)'|=|dF(\gamma')|=|\gamma'|$$ so $|(F\circ\gamma)'|$ is constant. Also for $t\in I$ and $J,r,s$ as in the definition above
$$d(F(\gamma(r)),F(\gamma(s)))=d(\gamma(r),\gamma(s))=L(\gamma_{|[r,s]})=L((F\circ\gamma)_{|[r,s]})
$$
so $F\circ \gamma$ is locally shortest. Hence $F\circ\gamma$ is a geodesic.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, my problem is that I do not have the definition for geodesics you stated above. I only know that these hold for a geodesic in a specific normal neighborhoof of a point.

Comment: Ok, so the idea here is to show that a the image under $F$ of a geodesic in $M$ is also a piecewise geodesic in $N$ and then conclude that it's a geodesic?

Comment: Then you can do it like this: Let $t\in I$. Take  normal neighbourhoods $V$  of $\gamma(t)$ and and $W$ of $F(\gamma(t))$  and set $U=V\cap F^{-1}(W)$. Then there is a neighbourhood $J$ of $t$ such that $\gamma_{|J}$ lies in $U$. Since then also $(F\circ\gamma)_{|J}$ lies in $W$ you can conclude that $(F\circ\gamma)''(t)=0$ and as $t$ was arbitrary $(F\circ\gamma)''=0$ so $F\circ\gamma$ is a geodesic.

Comment: Sorry i had a typo. Yes if you only know that then you can conclude first that $F\circ\gamma$ is a piecewise geodesic. But because it is smooth it is a geodesic.

Comment: Ok, thank you!!